# Minecraft Mouse Problem on Mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

In Minecraft (ver. 1.12.2), When I click on a block, The Block is not held by the mouse to be placed. I need to drag and drop blocks into my hotbar. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Be more specific. What type of click? Are you using a trackpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are trying to move items from your inventory to the Hotbar or from a chest to your inventory etc.

if that is the case, just press **Shift+Click** on the item you want to instantly go to the inventory and it will instantly go